# Cannot start apache kafka from command line on hortonworks sandbox

Tags: apache-kafka, hortonworks-sandbox

I need to override server.properties for kafka to add advertised host name, advertised listener and advertised port.

I tried changing server.properties and restarting kafka from ambari but the server.properties go back to previous values once the kafka server is up.

Then i figured i could start zookeeper and kafka from command line. I tried

`/usr/hdp/current/zookeeper-server/bin/zkServer.sh start`

The zookeeper started fine and reflected that it started in ambari but

```
/usr/hdp/3.0.1.0-187/kafka/bin/kafka-server-start.sh /usr/hdp/3.0.1.0-187/kafka/config/server.properties --override advertised.host.name=localhost --override  advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT
://:sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:6667 --override advertised.port=6667
```

This did not start kafka server or not atleast when i tried some consumers and did not reflect in the Ambari GUI.

The ports are mentioned in the properties file, any leads on how to override advertised listeners? And if yes what should be the advertised host name, listener and port values?

I am attaching the properties files, IP addresses for both windows(Host OS) and sandbox.

Sandbox IP: 172.18.0.2

Windows IP: 192.168.0.21

This is **consumer.properties**

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
# 
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
# 
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
# see org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig for more details

# list of brokers used for bootstrapping knowledge about the rest of the cluster
# format: host1:port1,host2:port2 ...
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092

# consumer group id
group.id=test-consumer-group

# What to do when there is no initial offset in Kafka or if the current
# offset does not exist any more on the server: latest, earliest, none
#auto.offset.reset=
```

This is **producer.properties**

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
# see org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig for more details

############################# Producer Basics #############################

# list of brokers used for bootstrapping knowledge about the rest of the cluster
# format: host1:port1,host2:port2 ...
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092

# specify the compression codec for all data generated: none, gzip, snappy, lz4
compression.type=none

# name of the partitioner class for partitioning events; default partition spreads data randomly
#partitioner.class=

# the maximum amount of time the client will wait for the response of a request
#request.timeout.ms=

# how long `KafkaProducer.send` and `KafkaProducer.partitionsFor` will block for
#max.block.ms=

# the producer will wait for up to the given delay to allow other records to be sent so that the sends can be batched together
#linger.ms=

# the maximum size of a request in bytes
#max.request.size=

# the default batch size in bytes when batching multiple records sent to a partition
#batch.size=

# the total bytes of memory the producer can use to buffer records waiting to be sent to the server
#buffer.memory=
```

This is **server.properties**

```
# Generated by Apache Ambari. Sun May  3 19:25:08 2020

auto.create.topics.enable=true
auto.leader.rebalance.enable=true
compression.type=producer
controlled.shutdown.enable=true
controlled.shutdown.max.retries=3
controlled.shutdown.retry.backoff.ms=5000
controller.message.queue.size=10
controller.socket.timeout.ms=30000
default.replication.factor=1
delete.topic.enable=true
external.kafka.metrics.exclude.prefix=kafka.network.RequestMetrics,kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory,kafka.server.BrokerTopicMetrics.BytesRejectedPerSec
external.kafka.metrics.include.prefix=kafka.network.RequestMetrics.ResponseQueueTimeMs.request.OffsetCommit.98percentile,kafka.network.RequestMetrics.ResponseQueueTimeMs.request.Offsets.95percentile,kafka.network.RequestMetrics.ResponseSendTimeMs.request.Fetch.95percentile,kafka.network.RequestMetrics.RequestsPerSec.request
fetch.purgatory.purge.interval.requests=10000
kafka.ganglia.metrics.group=kafka
kafka.ganglia.metrics.host=localhost
kafka.ganglia.metrics.port=8671
kafka.ganglia.metrics.reporter.enabled=true
kafka.metrics.reporters=
kafka.timeline.metrics.host_in_memory_aggregation=
kafka.timeline.metrics.host_in_memory_aggregation_port=
kafka.timeline.metrics.host_in_memory_aggregation_protocol=
kafka.timeline.metrics.hosts=
kafka.timeline.metrics.maxRowCacheSize=10000
kafka.timeline.metrics.port=
kafka.timeline.metrics.protocol=
kafka.timeline.metrics.reporter.enabled=true
kafka.timeline.metrics.reporter.sendInterval=5900
kafka.timeline.metrics.truststore.password=
kafka.timeline.metrics.truststore.path=
kafka.timeline.metrics.truststore.type=
leader.imbalance.check.interval.seconds=300
leader.imbalance.per.broker.percentage=10
listeners=PLAINTEXT://sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:6667
log.cleanup.interval.mins=10
log.dirs=/kafka-logs
log.index.interval.bytes=4096
log.index.size.max.bytes=10485760
log.retention.bytes=-1
log.retention.check.interval.ms=600000
log.retention.hours=168
log.roll.hours=168
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
message.max.bytes=1000000
min.insync.replicas=1
num.io.threads=8
num.network.threads=3
num.partitions=1
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
num.replica.fetchers=1
offset.metadata.max.bytes=4096
offsets.commit.required.acks=-1
offsets.commit.timeout.ms=5000
offsets.load.buffer.size=5242880
offsets.retention.check.interval.ms=600000
offsets.retention.minutes=86400000
offsets.topic.compression.codec=0
offsets.topic.num.partitions=50
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
offsets.topic.segment.bytes=104857600
port=6667
producer.metrics.enable=false
producer.purgatory.purge.interval.requests=10000
queued.max.requests=500
replica.fetch.max.bytes=1048576
replica.fetch.min.bytes=1
replica.fetch.wait.max.ms=500
replica.high.watermark.checkpoint.interval.ms=5000
replica.lag.max.messages=4000
replica.lag.time.max.ms=10000
replica.socket.receive.buffer.bytes=65536
replica.socket.timeout.ms=30000
sasl.enabled.mechanisms=GSSAPI
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=GSSAPI
security.inter.broker.protocol=PLAINTEXT
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
ssl.client.auth=none
ssl.key.password=
ssl.keystore.location=
ssl.keystore.password=
ssl.truststore.location=
ssl.truststore.password=
zookeeper.connect=sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=25000
zookeeper.session.timeout.ms=30000
zookeeper.sync.time.ms=2000
```

This is **zookeeper.properties**

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
# 
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
# 
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
# the directory where the snapshot is stored.
dataDir=/tmp/zookeeper
# the port at which the clients will connect
clientPort=2181
# disable the per-ip limit on the number of connections since this is a non-production config
maxClientCnxns=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Cannot be sure if you are hitting this, but the generic solution to 'I changed properties and my change disappeared' can be explained as follows:

There are config files used by the services, these are managed by Ambari.

It is possible to change these files directly, but this is not recommended as Ambari will simply overwrite them as soon as it gets the chance.

As such the root cause of your problem may be that you updated configs directly in the file, rather than through Ambari.

---

You may also want to check out this thread: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Producing-to-Kafka-HDP-Sandbox-2-6-4/td-p/189742